# I'm getting Unity error:CS1002: ; expected, how do I fix this because when I put the semi-colon in front of using UnityEngine.ui it creates 6 errors

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is the code I'm using

When I add a semi-colon to UnityEngine.ui then I get error messages CS0234 CS0116 CS0246
using UnityEngine.ui

```
public class Playermovement : MonoBehaviour
{

}
    public Transform PlayerTransform;
    public float PlayerSpeed;
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W));
        {
            PlayerTransform.TransLate(0.0f, PlayerSpeed, 0.0f);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A));
        {
            PlayerTransform.TransLate(-1.0f * PlayerSpeed, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S));
        {
            PlayerTransform.TransLate(0.0f, -1.0f * PlayerSpeed, 0.0f);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D));
        {
            PlayerTransform.TransLate(PlayerSpeed, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should remove the `;` character from the end of the `if` lines.

Comment: you should remove } line at 4.
And also Translate not TransLate

Answer (score 1):

This should work, removed `;` after `if` statements, fixed typo: `TransLate` to `Translate`, and indentation.

```cs
public class Playermovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform PlayerTransform;
    public float PlayerSpeed;
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            PlayerTransform.Translate(0.0f, PlayerSpeed, 0.0f);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            PlayerTransform.Translate(-1.0f * PlayerSpeed, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            PlayerTransform.Translate(0.0f, -1.0f * PlayerSpeed, 0.0f);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            PlayerTransform.Translate(PlayerSpeed, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, do this in your `Update()` method

```cs
void Update()
{
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    PlayerTransform.Translate(x * PlayerSpeed, y * PlayerSpeed, 0.0f);
}
```